# See conversion rate of specific event in Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Anytime a customer completes the payment of a order on our website, we send an analytics event with the following data:

```
Category: Order
Action: Status
Label: Complete
```

Now I want to see in what kind of rate sessions achieve this goal over time. I can't seem the find this view.

So that I can see for instance:

- On 08/**01**/2017 **31%** of the sessions sent this event
- On 08/**02**/2017 **32%** of the sessions sent this event
- On 08/**03**/2017 **30%** of the sessions sent this event
- etc.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is best done with a Goal; you can set the goal up to count Session where the event was triggered.

Unfortunately, this won't work retrospectively. If you want to do that, I recommend defining a Segment as 'Sessions which included Event X', and looking at the number of Sessions that that Segment has.

EDIT:
As pointed out by Eike, I should clarify that both of these methods would only count up to one event per Session. If you want to potentially count multiple events per Session, you'd need a different method.

Comment: A goal can only be reached once per session, though (I think this was specifically done by Google to avoid conversion rates > 100%), so it might not work if there are multiple purchases per sessions.

Comment: @EikePierstorff you're right, of course, but that's how I interpreted the question, as he said 'X% of sessions sent this event'; if you block divided events by Sessions you could end up with 100% 'conversion' just because a 20% of your audience completed the event 5 times.